# Creating request from new session

Tags: servlets, single-sign-on

I am trying to log into a single sign on protected home page by skipping the login page of a web based application .
I got authenticated session and cookie by making a call to method, exposed through Soap based webservice.

How can i  make a request (or redirect response), using this authenticated session through  servlet so that i can bypass login page.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.